# Не форматирует json

Tags: c#

Подскажите, почему я получаю не ровный столбец в notepad, а вот такое

```
"{\r\n  \"1\": {\r\n    \"2\": \"1\",\r\n    \"1234\": \"5689\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
```

Добавляю так :

```
Dictionary<string, string> tt2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
tt2.Add(textBox2.Text, textBox1.Text);
tt2.Add("1234", "5689");
tt.Add(textBox1.Text, tt2);
string tt3 = JsonHelper.Serialize(tt);
JsonHelper.SaveFile(tt3, path);


public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
            {             
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
            }

    public static void SaveFile<T>(T obj, string path)
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
                serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        File.Delete(path);
                    }

                    StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path);

                    using (JsonWriter writerr = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(writerr, obj);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //
                }
            }
```

Comment: А зачем вы сериализуете в строку, а потом полученную JSON-строку сериализуете снова?

Comment: @VladD думал поможет - без 1-ой сериализации все равно все в 1 строку {"123":{"123":"123","1234":"5689"}}

Comment: Оставьте другую сериализацию) Которая JsonConvert

Comment: @Михаил: Ну, вы представляете себе назначение ваших методов? Или вы их откуда-то скопировали просто?